# PHP Laravel 4 - Database table "as"

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating a backend interface for a site made in Joomla. I am using Laravel to create the backend. Joomla has table prefixes and tend to have long table names there are some of which around 25 characters.

My issue is, I have looked around to see if that you can alias table names (so I don't have to type the table name all the time in the join statement) by I don't seem to be able to find a method for this in the query object.

ModelName::getTable(); // Happens to be a static method.

Any helper much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered in that StackOverflow question:

[How to alias a table in Laravel Eloquent queries (or using Query Builder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder)

you can either use aliases while building your query

```
$users = DB::table('really_long_table_name AS t')
       ->select('t.id AS uid')
       ->get();
```

or define the alias in your Eloquent model

```
protected $table = 'really_long_table_name AS short_name';
```

Comment: You shouldn't define the alias in the models. It will cause problems on inserts or updates. insert into really_long_table_name AS short_name ...

Comment: I agree with @c4pone