# Can't get SQL query in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.1

How can I get this query in laravel 5.1. I have model **Menu**, database **menus**. This query in SQL get results I want.

```
SELECT b.title FROM menus a, menus b WHERE a.id=b.parent_id
```

Same thing, I can't get for this query

```
SELECT m.* FROM menus m WHERE m.id in (select m2.parent_id from menus m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel docs for queries](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) has an example that you can improvise on:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Try to use something similar and note that you can [use aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder):

```
$variable = DB::table('menus as a')
            ->join('menus as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.parent_id')
            ->select('b.title')
            ->get();
```

Look at [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in) for an example of `where in` equivalent.