# How to add alias statement

Tags: mysql, laravel, alias

How to add alias statement? 
Here is the original code :

```
DB::table(DB::raw('manager as a'))
   ->leftJoin('parameter as p',function($join){
        $join->on('a.vipStatus','=','p.code')  
    })
   ->where('a.active','=','1');
```

and I transfer sql like this

```
$this->manager
     ->leftJoin('parameter as p',function($join){
        $join->on('manager.vipStatus','=','p.code')    
     })
     ->where('manager.active','=','1');
```

`$this->manager` use __construct() inject a manager table ,
How to change `manager.vipStatus` to `a.vipStatus`?

Comment: Give this example a look if you haven't already. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31624248/1133306

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alias a table in Laravel Eloquent queries (or using Query Builder)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder)