# Convert raw SQL to Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have an query and sub query but it's still in Raw SQL Form. I want to change in Query Builder Laravel. But I got some problem with that especially in Aliases (AS) from Sub Query in order to be reusable for further condition.

Here's my raw
[sql](https://pastebin.com/RvvDMHv8).

And here's my query builder:

```
  $sub_query = DB::table('orders')
                ->join('order_details', 'orders.order_id', '=', 'order_details.order_id')
                ->leftjoin('shipment_details', 'shipment_details.order_detail_id', '=', 'order_details.order_detail_id')
                ->leftjoin('shipment_headers', 'shipment_headers.shipment_header_id', '=', 'shipment_details.shipment_header_id')
                ->where('orders.order_mask_id', '=', 'TZ4CFI')
                ->select('order_details.order_detail_id', 'shipment_details.qty')
                ->groupBy('order_details.order_detail_id');

    $result_2 = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub_query->toSql()}) AS sub") )
        ->mergeBindings($sub_query);

    $result_2 = $result_2->from('orders')
        ->join('customers', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->join('order_details', 'orders.order_id', '=', 'order_details.order_id')
        ->join('products', 'order_details.product_id', '=', 'products.product_id')
        ->join('merchants', 'products.merchant_id', '=', 'merchants.merchant_id')
        ->join('product_subcategories', 'products.product_subcategory_id', '=', 'product_subcategories.product_subcategory_id')
        ->join('product_categories', 'product_subcategories.product_category_id', '=', 'product_categories.product_category_id')
        ->join('product_super_categories', 'product_categories.product_super_category_id', '=', 'product_super_categories.product_super_category_id')
        ->where('orders.order_mask_id', '=', 'TZ4CFI')
        ->where('sub.order_detail_id', '=', 'order_details.order_detail_id')
        ->whereRaw('(order_details.qty - sub.qty) != 0');

    $result_2 =   $result_2->select('orders.order_mask_id', 'orders.created_at', 'customers.email', 'customers.name', 'product_super_categories.product_super_category_name', 'product_categories.product_category_name', 'product_subcategories.product_subcategory_name', 'products.product_name', 
                    DB::raw('
                        order_details.qty - qty AS qty
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        IF(products.is_perishable, "Perishable", "Non Perishable") AS is_perishable
                    '), 
                    'merchants.merchant_name', 'orders.order_payment_type', 'orders.order_payment_status', 'orders.order_status', 
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS shipment_status
                    '), 
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS seller_name
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS shipping_carrier_name
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS shipping_service_name
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS tracking_number
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS scheduled_ship_date
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS actual_ship_date
                    '),
                    DB::raw('
                        "-" AS delivery_date 
                    '))->get();
     dd($result_2);
```

Comment: Put your SQL in the question.

Comment: try to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder/31624248