# How to alias table in Laravel using newQuery()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with the name `cotacaoitensfranqueado` and I'd like to call it using just `cif`, I know I can do this `DB::table('cotacaoitensfranqueado as cif')` how I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder/17713900), but I'd like to do that using my model.

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    $model_cotacaoitensfranqueado = new Cotacaoitensfranqueado();

    $query = $model_cotacaoitensfranqueado->newQuery();
    $query->select('cotacaoitensfranqueado.*', 'c.status');
    $query->join('cotacao as c', [
       ['c.codigoconcentrador', 'cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigoconcentrador'],
       ['c.codigoempresa', 'cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigoempresa'],
       ['c.codigocotacao', 'cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigocotacao'],
    ]);
    $query->where('cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigoconcentrador', (int)$user->codigoconcentrador)
        ->where('cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigoempresa', (int)$codigoempresa)
        ->where('cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigofilial', $user->codigofilial)
        ->where('cotacaoitensfranqueado.codigocotacao', (int)$codigocotacao)
        ->where('c.status', 'A');

    $cotacao = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize how to solve the problem, you can do the alias in the model

**Cotacaoitensfranqueado.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cotacaoitensfranqueado extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cotacaoitensfranqueado as cif';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Controller/CotacaoController.php**

```
...
use App\Cotacaoitensfranqueado;

class CotacaoController extends Controller
{
   ...

   public function canSendBuy($codigoempresa, $codigocotacao){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $model_cotacaoitensfranqueado = new Cotacaoitensfranqueado();

        $query = $model_cotacaoitensfranqueado->query();
        $query->select('cif.*', 'c.status');
        $query->join('cotacao as c', [
           ['c.codigoconcentrador', 'cif.codigoconcentrador'],
           ['c.codigoempresa', 'cif.codigoempresa'],
           ['c.codigocotacao', 'cif.codigocotacao'],
        ]);
        $query->where('cif.codigoconcentrador', (int)$user->codigoconcentrador)
            ->where('cif.codigoempresa', (int)$codigoempresa)
            ->where('cif.codigofilial', $user->codigofilial)
            ->where('cif.codigocotacao', (int)$codigocotacao)
            ->where('c.status', 'A');

        $cotacao = $query->get();

        dd($cotacao);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `newQuery()` or `(int)` with Eloquent:

```
Cotacaoitensfranqueado::where('codigoconcentrador', auth()->user()->codigoconcentrador)->get();
```

But if you really want to use it, use `query()` instead because `newQuery()` is deprecated.

Comment: thanks for answering, how do I alias the table in this way?

Comment: @SpaceDogCS you don't need to alias data, because Eloquent will return a collection of objects.

Comment: @SpaceDogCS I mean Eloquent doesn't use this info anyway. Just look into the result of `dd(Cotacaoitensfranqueado::where('codigoconcentrador', auth()->user()->codigoconcentrador)->get());` do understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: I understand, I just want to shorten the name of the table, so it get easier to make joins, etc

Comment: @SpaceDogCS ok. When you use `join()`, it's Query Builder you use, not Eloquent ORM. So, you can use the `DB::table()` way to create an alias.