# how to get id from joined table sql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I have a joined table from siswa and kelas. in kelas table there is a column idSiswa, it comes from id from siswa table. the question is how I can get the id from kelas when its joined. when I try to fetch id it shows the id from siswa table, not from kelas table, I also already used right join and left join and still not get the answer

this is my kelas table
[image: this is my kelas table]

this is my siswa table
[image: this is my siswa table]

I using a query builder from laravel to run the query, and this is my query

```
$siswa = DB::table('siswas')
            ->join('kelas', 'kelas.idSiswa', '=', 'siswas.id')
            ->where([
                ['kelas.kelas', '2'],
                ['kelas.semester', 'ganjil'],

            ])
            ->select('kelas.*', 'siswas.*')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from a name conflict. When you join your two tables, there are 2 `fields`. To solve it, you should use SQL alias.
You can see an example on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713730/how-to-alias-a-table-in-laravel-eloquent-queries-or-using-query-builder)

You could also consider using Eloquent which offers OOP advantages and automatically avoids this kind of issues.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kelas extends Model
{
    public function siswa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Siswa', 'idSiswa', 'kelas');
    }
}
```

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Siswa extends Model
{
    public function kelas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Kelas', 'idSiswa', 'kelas');
    }
}
```

```
$siswa = App\Siswa::with('kelas')
    ->where([
        ['kelas', '2'],
        ['semester', 'ganjil'],
    ])
    ->get();

$firstSiswaKelasIds = $siswa->first()->kelas->map->id;
```