# Another way to change the name of a table in Laravel using App\Models\XXX name

Tags: laravel

Simple question...
I can **change the name of a table** in a query like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users AS u')->select('name');
```

Can i do it in some way like this?

```
$users = App\Models\Users::select('name')->get();
```

Comment: Laravel Query builder automatically assign the alise name to table. Request if you can provide more details what you want to achieve from this or if you are facing some issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624248/379888)),

```
App\Models\Users::from( 'users as u' )
    ->select( 'name' )
    ->get();
```

To get the name directly from the table ([source](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-table-name-from-model-in-laravel-5example.html)),

```
$users = new Users;
$table = $users->getTable();
print_r($table);
```

Comment: Yes, this will do it. 
But is there a way to not give the initial name of the table?
If my Model i have set 
protected $table = 'user';

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$users = Users::from('users AS u')
               // Extra Logic
               ->where('u.//field' , '=' , $data)
               ->select('u.name')
               ->get();
```

Hope It will help You!

Answer (score 0):

This's called table "Alias" and it's meaningless to set alias in the model, simply because you don't need to define any table name when you're using Laravel ORM.

But in query builder you can set aliases specially when you're trying to join same table multiple times:

```
 DB::table('table_name AS alias_name');
```

or in join

```
$query->join('table_name as alias_name', function ($builder) use ($value) {}
```